# Apachi POI - Cell setCellValue thows NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache-poi

When I am trying to update existing excel file I am encountering following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xltest.main(xltest.java:28)
```

My code:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\onu\\test.xlsx"));

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Update the value of cell
Cell cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(3); // cell D1
cell.setCellValue("onu"); // line 28 which throws NPE

file.close();

FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\onu\\test.xlsx"));
workbook.write(outFile);
outFile.close();
```

Answer (score 14):

The cell does not exist yet, so `getCell` returns `null`.

You must detect this and create the cell if it doesn't exist, with [the `createCell` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#createCell%28int%29):

```
if (cell == null)
{
    cell = sheet.getRow(0).createCell(3);
}
// Then set the value.
cell.setCellValue("onu");
```

Alternatively, there is [an overload of `getCell`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell%28int,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy%29) where you can specify a `MissingCellPolicy` so that a blank `Cell` is automatically created if it didn't already exist:

```
cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(3, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```